# How do I search a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: c#, search, multidimensional-array, find

In C#,

```
Array.Find<T>(arrayName, value);
```

searches a one dimensional array. Is there anyway to do this for a multidimensional array (e.g. `myArray[,,]`)?

Comment: If you need to do such an `O(dimension_1 * dimension_2 * ... * dimension_n)` search more than a few times, you've propably done something very wrong when selecting algorithm and data structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Working with Excel and VSTO, I deal with multidimensional arrays all the time. There are no built-in functions for multidimensional array like Array.Find().

You basically have two choices: create your own helper methods and implement a generic search pattern there, or generate a list of domain objects correlating to the contents of the multidimensional array. I personally have tended to choose the latter option.

If you choose to write a helper method, it could look something (very roughly) like this:

```
// you could easily modify this code to handle 3D arrays, etc.
public static class ArrayHelper
{
    public static object FindInDimensions(this object[,] target, 
      object searchTerm)
    {
        object result = null;
        var rowLowerLimit = target.GetLowerBound(0);
        var rowUpperLimit = target.GetUpperBound(0);

        var colLowerLimit = target.GetLowerBound(1);
        var colUpperLimit = target.GetUpperBound(1);

        for (int row = rowLowerLimit; row < rowUpperLimit; row++)
        {
            for (int col = colLowerLimit; col < colUpperLimit; col++)
            {
                // you could do the search here...
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

You would refer to the static extension like this in other parts of your application code:

```
object[,] myArray = GetMyArray(); // gets an array[,]
myArray.FindInDimensions(someObject);
```

Comment: all the upper-limits should be ++ or the < need to be <=

Comment: Great solution.  You're right, working w/ VSTO and Excel this is very useful.

Answer (score 3):

There is no built in multi-dimensional search function. You'd have to write it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Flatten the multidimensional array and then use `Array.Find`.

Comment: The flattening process would take longer than just looping through and searching.

Comment: @TheLQ: I agree, inlining the search with the flattening process is the better approach.