# C# Two Dimensional Array and Array.Find - Cannot Convert Error

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a two dimensional array declared.  It has two columns - filename and batch.  I initialize it empty.

```
string[,] a_Reports = new string[,] { { "", "" } };
```

I have some code that resizes it and populates it.  Everything is a string value.  When I go to look up an element in the array like so:

```
int value1 = Array.Find<string>(a_Reports, element=>element.Equals(newFileName));
```

I get the error:

```
CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string[*,*]' to 'string[]'
```

I've tried it every which way and nothing works.   Please help me!!!  I've spent hours on it already.

Comment: I think error message is clear. Don't use `Array.Find` on `string[,]`

Comment: Shouldn't it be : Find<string, string>

Comment: Find<string><string> was a good idea but it didn't work.  I thought there would be an easier way than traversing the array and I thought .Find would be it but I guess the syntax is not obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array.Find is only for one-dimensional arrays. ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9hy2xwa(v=vs.110).aspx))

Check out this answer on '[How do I search a multi-dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6085012/2239678)'

Produce a similar extension method, like [in my example on rextester](http://rextester.com/AXBB30675).

Or use a jagged array instead of a two-dimensional one and a combination of foreach and find, like:

```
string[][] jagged = ...
Array.ForEach(jagged, array=>Array.Find(array, x=>x=="" ));
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  I ended up making an array scan function.